# Instead of updating record update command making new entries

Tags: sql-server

At the time of running update command, it inserts it as a new entry and not updating the previous one. Username is the Foreign key in the insert table. Instead of updating record update command making new entries.

I have written a stored procedure to insert data:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE Login_insert
    @Name nvarchar(50),
    @Address varchar(50),
    @City varchar(50),
    @DateOfBirth datetime,
    @Username nvarchar(50)
AS 
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO NewUser 
    VALUES (@Name, @Address, @City, @DateOfBirth, @Username)
END
```

and calling it from my C# code like this:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int count = 0;

    SqlCommand command;

    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=DESKTOP-HKML31V\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=DB;Integrated Security=True");
    con.Open();

    if (count > 0)
    {
        command = new SqlCommand("UPDATE NewUser SET Name = @Name, Address = @Address, City = @City, DateofBith = @DateofBirth WHERE Id = @Username", con);
    }
    else 
    {
        command = new SqlCommand("Login_insert", con);
        command.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;

        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("Name", TextBox1.Text);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("Address", TextBox2.Text);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("City", TextBox3.Text);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("DateofBirth", TextBox4.Text);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("Username", Label1.Text);
    }

    int rowsupdated = command.ExecuteNonQuery();  
}
```

Comment: Since you explicitly set `count` to 0 at the beginning of your button click handler, of course it's always the `INSERT` stored procedure that's being called (since the `if (count > 0)` condition is **never** true) - so what's your question really??

Comment: I want if he finds record then update otherwise insert a new record. But its always inserting new records.

Comment: So i should set the count =1

Comment: But you're never even **looking for** the record ......

Comment: I would probably put everything into the stored procedure - pass in all the values, and let the stored procedure check first if the record you're interested in exists - if so, update it - if not, insert a new record

Comment: Can you guide me. How to make it.?

Comment: Don't use [addwithvalue](http://www.dbdelta.com/addwithvalue-is-evil/)

Comment: DateOfBirth is  DATE, not a datetime. THINK about your datatypes!

Answer (score 0):

I would probably package the whole logic into the stored procedure: pass in all the values, and let the stored procedure check first if the record you're interested in exists - if so, update it - if not, insert a new record

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.InsertOrUpdateUser
    @Name nvarchar(50),
    @Address varchar(50),
    @City varchar(50),
    @DateOfBirth datetime,
    @Username nvarchar(50)
AS 
BEGIN
    -- check if the user already exists
    IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM dbo.NewUser WHERE Id = @Username)
    BEGIN
        -- user does exist - update it
        UPDATE NewUser 
        SET Name = @Name, 
            Address = @Address, 
            City = @City, 
            DateofBith =  @DateofBirth 
        WHERE Id = @Username
    END
    ELSE BEGIN
        -- user does not exist - insert a new entry
        INSERT INTO NewUser (Name, Address, City, DateOfBirth, Id)
        VALUES (@Name, @Address, @City, @DateOfBirth, @Username)
    END
END
```

and then just call this stored procedure from your C# code:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=DESKTOP-HKML31V\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=DB;Integrated Security=True");

    SqlCommand cmdInsertOrUpdate = new SqlCommand("dbo.InsertOrUpdateUser", con);
    cmdInsertOrUpdate .CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

    cmdInsertOrUpdate.Parameters.Add("@Name", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50).Value =  TextBox1.Text;
    cmdInsertOrUpdate.Parameters.Add("@Address", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50).Value = TextBox2.Text;
    cmdInsertOrUpdate.Parameters.Add("@City", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50).Value = TextBox3.Text;
    cmdInsertOrUpdate.Parameters.Add("@DateofBirth", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = Convert.ToDateTime(TextBox4.Text);
    cmdInsertOrUpdate.Parameters.Add("@Username", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50).Value = Label1.Text;

    con.Open();
    int rowsupdated = cmdInsertOrUpdate.ExecuteNonQuery();  
    con.Close();
}
```

Comment: cmdInsertOrUpdate.Parameters.Add("@Username", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50).Value = Label1.Text;      It showing error in this line that unable to convert Nvarchar

Comment: @BhartiSingh: well - what is the value of `Label1.Text` ?

Comment: It is the value of Username

Comment: @BhartiSingh: maybe the datetime conversion on the previous line is really the cause - can you try to use this line for the date of birth (just to test if this works): `cmdInsertOrUpdate.Parameters.Add("@DateofBirth", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = DateTime.Today.AddYears(-50);` - if you run this - does it work?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62195730/error-at-the-time-of-execution-of-stored-procedure.     Sir please see this question